# how to pass string(s) stored in a variable to sybase SQL IN clause from bash script

Tags: bash

I have an array of say empId's which are of typr String , now i want to pass it in IN clause of SQL from bash.

I had tried below

```
#make an array of empIds

empIdsarray=(e123 e456 e675 e897)
for j in "${empIdsarray[@]}"
do
   inclause=\"$j\",$inclause
done
#remove the trailing comma below
inclause=`echo $inclause|sed 's/,$//'
`isql -U$user -P$pwd -D$db -S$server <<< QRY > tempRS.txt
    select * from emp where empId IN ($inclause)
go
quit
go
QRY`
```

i had tried IN('$inclause') as well but nothing is working , the output is blank although when i run in DB directly it gives result .
Any help is appreciated .

```
#it should execute like
select * from emp where empId IN ("e123", "e456", "e675", "e897")
```

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BASH you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
#make an array of empIds
empIdsarray=(e123 e456 e675 e897)
printf -v inclause '"%s",' "${empIdsarray[@]}"

isql -U$user -P$pwd -D$db -S$server <<QRY > tempRS.txt
select * from emp where empId IN (${inclause%,})
go
quit
go
QRY
```